# Why recently, after videos are played in a personal playlist it then starts playing some random mix

Tags: youtube

I use YouTube primarily for music videos, to listen to while working.  Recently, it changed so that now after one song in my ***Favorites playlist*** plays it then goes to some ***mix*** and starts playing songs there.  It seems to be arbitrary and doesn't always do it.

Any idea why that is going on, and how to fix it.  I've looked at the settings and can't find anything that would help.  Note, I'm usually on another tab when it happens, so it's not me hitting some button when it's done.

Update:  Just had it happen for video I was playing outside of a playlist.  It ended, and then went to another video by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out they implemented a new feature (without help documentation so far).  It's called Autoplay, and you have to turn it off (no idea how it got turned on, or if they just started it "on" for everyone).

[image: Autoplay Snapsho]

Note that this didn't show up on the page when I was playing my Favorites playlist, but only on a separate video page.

Comment: Yep, this fixed the issue of YouTube going out of the current playlist into other videos. And yes, it happens mostly when the YouTube tab is in the background.

BTW, it doesn't happen with the first songs, or small playlists. I see this happening on a big playlist (800+ items) when around the 400+ positions.